# 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' error window opens twice when I debug code

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012

When I debug and run a project on VS 2012 a window opens twice saying "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll"and I always click continue then after debug is finished it says that it is ready but the window of my project doesn't open. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Expand the details to see where your bad XAML is. You have a syntax error somewhere that you need to rectify before your window can be successfully constructed and rendered.

Comment: But when I build the project it doesn't appear any errors, I have looked to see if there are syntax errors and I can't find. The code source for my project is this https://github.com/fatihboy/Robosapien/blob/master/RobosapienKinect/MainWindow.xaml.cs